# Alternative to Sparrow for Windows?

Tags: windows, sparrow

Sparrow is a convenient email client to handle Gmail on the desktop. It is available only for Mac and iPhone. Is there a clone or alternative to that on Windows?

Comment: As far as I know, it's Apple only.

Comment: @RandolphWest: ... "It is available only for Mac" ...

Comment: Which features of Sparrow would you even need? Most importantly: Which e-mail clients have you already tried and why didn't they work for you? What problem are you facing? Polling for a list of answers is really not a good fit for the site – essentially, this is a buying recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

[Inbox2](http://inbox2.com/) or [postbox](http://www.postbox-inc.com/) might be options.